# Perl - Need help populating Term::ANSIMenu with items from an existing array

Tags: arrays, perl

Trying to use [Term::ANSIMenu](http://p3rl.org/Term%3a%3aANSIMenu) to build a nice menu.

The doc says `items()` expects an array of arrays:

```
items()

Type: array of arrays
Constraints: [[<keyname>, <string>, <code_ref>], ...]
Default: []
```

So this works fine:

```
my $menu = Term::ANSIMenu->new(
    items  => [['1', 'First menu item', \&exec_item],
               ['2', 'And so on', \&exec_item],
              ]) ;
```

What I need to do is feed `items()` with strings in an existing array (that gets dynamically created by my program - it may contain any number of strings).

e.g.

```
@array = ('menu choice one', 'menu choice two', 'menu choice three') ;
```

I'm struggling to create an "array of arrays" that I can then pass to `items()`.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass [reference to array](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References)

Should looks like:

```
@array = (['1', 'First menu item', \&exec_item]); 
push @array, ['2', 'And so on', \&exec_item];

my $menu = Term::ANSIMenu->new(items => \@array);
```

Comment: `my @menu_items = () ;
my @tmp = ();
my $counter = 1 ;
foreach my $item (@available_choices) {
  @tmp = ( "$counter", "$item", '\&process_item()' ) ;
  push @menu_items, [ @tmp ] ;
  $counter++ ;
}
my $menu = Term::ANSIMenu->new(width  => 40,
                               title  => 'Choose your fate or die!',
                               items  => \@menu_items,
                               prompt => 'Selection:> ');

$menu->print_menu();`

Above results in "Invalid value for items: ARRAY(0x9110f0c)"

Comment: @NormaStitz I think you just misunderstood [Term::ANSIMenu](https://metacpan.org/module/Term::ANSIMenu) documentation: third element in each item array should be coderef associated with that button or nothing. 
Here's example of working code for your case: https://gist.github.com/4ea508b0e8e865ab1fdd

Comment: Thanks for pushing this further. You're right that eliminating the third element make print_menu() work, but I actually do want/need to associate a coderef; basically a function to process the user's selection. No matter how I try formatting things, though, as soon as I add a 3rd element I get the "invalid value" error.

Comment: In your snippet you are trying to pass just a string instead of coderef. To do this right way, you need to define subroutine and pass it's name as third element like '\&handle_menu_item` for example. 
I updated my gist, please see link above

Comment: Yay!! Thank you! Removing the quotes fixed my code. THANK YOU!

Comment: @NormaStitz did you also know that [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is the best way to say thank you on stackoverflow? I don't try to force you to accept mine, but I see you have other question with not accepted answer..

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow... looking for the accept answer button, now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\@` to reference an existing array:

```
my @multiDimensionalArray = (\@preexistingArray1, \@preexistingArray2, ...);
```

or

```
my $multiDimensionalArrayRef = [\@preexistingArray1, 
                  \@preexistingArray2, ...]; # square brackets for array ref!
```

so then for `items`:

```
...
items => \@multiDimensionalArray
...
```

or

```
...
items => $multiDimensionalArrayRef
...
```